# Dynamic choosing of data by month where the specific date is less than the last day of each month

Tags: date, google-bigquery

I need to get aggregated data by month for the last 12 months where the specific criteria is smaller or equal to the last day of each month. From the previous employee I have inherited the report which simply consists of unions of such a script for each month:

```
select '2017_11' as 'Period', AccountId
from crm_account
where 
     ntw_StartedOnBoardingDate<=Timestamp('2017-11-30') and 
     (ntw_ChangedToLiveOn>Timestamp('2017-11-30') OR ntw_ChangedToLiveOn is null) and 
     (ntw_DisabledOn>Timestamp('2017-11-30') OR ntw_DisabledOn is null) and 
     statecode=0
```

The question is how can I do it dynamic thus it will get info not for the specific months but for `date_add(current_timestamp(), -12, 'month')`.
Thank you!

Comment: Could you add some sample input and respective output?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat difficult to answer, but this may point you in the right direction:

To pull the month (as the date of the first of the month) of the current month but from one year ago, try `SELECT DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE, MONTH), INTERVAL 12 MONTH)`